# How do you tell eglot and clangd about the compilation database (compile_commands.json)?

Tags: eglot

I'm trying to set up Emacs for C++ development, with IDE-like features. I installed [eglot](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot) and have got it working, somewhat. Flymake is drawing red error markers and reporting errors on `#include ...` lines, but everything compiles fine.

I wonder if these false errors are because I never told it about my `compile_commands.json` file. I use CMake, and at the root of my project I have a build/binary dir named `build-debug`. When I run `cmake` I generate the file, so it's there in `build-debug/compile_commands.json`.

Is there a way to tell eglot/clangd about this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: just add a symlink `ln -s build-debug/compile_commands.json` in your project root.

Comment: That appears to have worked. Thanks. How did you know that? Did I miss it in the docs somewhere?

Comment: See this: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html